# Tkinterでスクロールできるようにしたい

Tags: python, python2, tkinter, gui

いつもお世話になっております。

Python 2.7のTkinterを用いてGUIアプリにスクロールが
できる(ブラウザを見るときのような全体をスクロールできる)
機能を付けたいです。
様々なサイトを参考にしてみたのですが解決できませんでした。
垂直方向にまずはスクロールできるようにしたいのですが、
どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。
その際クラスは用いずにご説明していただけましたら、幸いです。

お手数をおかけいたしますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

どのような **Widget** を配置したいのかが書かれていないので想定となりますが、例えば **Canvas Widget** に **Scroll Bar** を付ける場合は以下のように

- **Root Window** 上に **Scrollbar Widget** と **Canvas Widget** を配置
- `Scrollbar.config(command=Canvas.yview)` にて**Scrollbar**を動かしたときに**Canvas**に通知する処理を追加
- `Canvas.config(scrollregion=())` にてScrollの範囲を設定
- `Canvas.config(yscrollcommand=Scrollbar.set)` にて**Canvas**の可動域を**Scrollbar**に通知する処理を追加

で動作するかと思います。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")

# Canvas Widget を生成して配置
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)

# Scrollbar を生成して配置
bar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
bar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

# Scrollbarを制御をCanvasに通知する処理を追加
bar.config(command=canvas.yview)

# Canvasのスクロール範囲を設定
canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,400,400))

# Canvasの可動域をScreoobarに通知する処理を追加
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=bar.set)

# Canvas上に適当な図形を書いておく
id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 370, 370)
canvas.itemconfigure(id, fill = 'red')

root.mainloop()
```

---

**Frame Widget** は残念ながら **Scrollbar** をサポートしていないのですが、上記の **Scrollbar**付きの **Canvas Widget** 上に **Frame Widget** を配置することで対応できるかと思います。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")

# Canvas Widget を生成
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)

# Scrollbar を生成して配置
bar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
bar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

# Scrollbarを制御をCanvasに通知する処理を追加
bar.config(command=canvas.yview)

# Canvasのスクロール範囲を設定
canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,400,400))

# Canvasの可動域をScreoobarに通知する処理を追加
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=bar.set)

# Frame Widgetを 生成
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

# Frame Widgetを Canvas Widget上に配置
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor=tk.NW, width=canvas.cget('width'))

# Frame上に適当なコンテンツを配置
tk.Label(frame, text="Hello World!!", font=("",24)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: まさにこのようなものを求めておりました。ありがとうございました。